# Group database rows by one of two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, grouping

**The goal**

I am trying to write a query to find duplicate rows. A row is duplicate when either Column A **or** Column B is the same.

Writing it so that both need to be the same is easy; just a simple `GROUP BY A, B`.

However, filtering by just one of the two is proving to be a bit more difficult. How would one go about doing this?

**I've tried the following:**

```
select distinct a as col_a,
                b as col_b,
                (
                    select count(*)
                    from table_name
                    where a = col_a
                       or b = col_b
                ) as duplicate_count
from table_name
having duplicate_count > 1;
```

but it does not feel like the right way to go about this and with 84.000 rows it is also very slow.

**Example**

With the following table:

```
+----+------------------------+---+---------+
| id | name                   | a | b       |
+----+------------------------+---+---------+
| 1  | Lorem ipsum            | 1 | Donec   |
+----+------------------------+---+---------+
| 2  | dolor sit              | 2 | rhoncus |
+----+------------------------+---+---------+
| 3  | amet                   | 3 | rhoncus |
+----+------------------------+---+---------+
| 4  | consectetur adipiscing | 1 | primis  |
+----+------------------------+---+---------+
| 5  | vulputate cursus       | 4 | Aliquam |
+----+------------------------+---+---------+
```

Either result 1 or 4 (same A) and either result 2 or 3 (same B) should be returned, both with a `duplicate_count` of 2.
Which one of the two "duplicates" is returned does not matter.

**Versions**

On my local machine I use MySQL 5.7.24.
I just checked the live server, it uses 10.1.43-MariaDB.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Also specify the version of MySQL that you are using.

Comment: How to determine one of the two you need to keep? is the record exactly the same?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I have tried to improve the question.

Answer (score 2):

You already know that this query:

```
select a, b
from tablename
group by a, b
having count(*) > 1
```

returns duplicates with both `a` and `b` equal.
You can get the **rest of the duplicates** for your requirement with `EXISTS`:

```
select t.a, t.b
from tablename t
where exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where (a = t.a and b <> t.b) or (a <> t.a and b = t.b)
)
```

Or if you want them all use `UNION ALL`:

```
select a, b
from tablename
group by a, b
having count(*) > 1
union all
select t.a, t.b
from tablename t
where exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where (a = t.a and b <> t.b) or (a <> t.a and b = t.b)
)
```

Update:
If you have an `ID` column then use EXISTS like this:

```
select t.*
from tablename t
where exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where id <> t.id and (a = t.a or b = t.b)
)
```

Or if you want just 1 of the duplicates use `id > t.id` instead of `id <> t.id`.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=467481961d105208524ecc93459792c9).
Or with a self join:

```
select t.*
from tablename t inner join tablename tt
on (tt.a = t.a or tt.b = t.b) and tt.id <> t.id
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, I appreciate it. Unfortunately, this has the same problem as the small bit of example code I've posted in the question, of it being very slow.

Comment: Check another way with a self join in my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Following solution works :

[Another demo with a line that has duplication in a and b](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b877e0d3580c187662fadf30548cc3d0)

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ab_duplicates (
a INTEGER
) AS 
SELECT  a, count(*) as cnt
FROM tablename
group by a, b
Having cnt > 1;
ALTER TABLE ab_duplicates ADD INDEX (a);

-- Select duplicates for a, but not for a and b
SELECT id, name, a, b
FROM   (SELECT x.*, t.id, t.name, t.a, t.b, 
               @rn := IF(t.a = @a, @rn + 1, 1) rn,
               @a := t.a,
               ab.a as ab_exists
          FROM (select @a := null, @rn := 0) x, 
               tablename t
                LEFT JOIN ab_duplicates ab on ab.a = t.a 
       ORDER BY a
    ) a_duplicates
where rn = 2 and ab_exists is null
UNION
-- union duplicates for b, including duplicates for a and b
SELECT id, name, a, b
FROM   (SELECT x.*, t.id, t.name, t.a, t.b, 
               @rn := IF(t.b = @b, @rn + 1, 1) rn,
               @b := t.b
          FROM (select @b := null, @rn := 0) x, 
               tablename t
       ORDER BY b
    ) b_and_ab_duplicates
where rn = 2;
```

## Previous solutions that only worked in some edge cases

Using group by and count() :

First finding ids with duplicates for a :

```
SELECT min(id) id, count(*) cnt from tablename t group by a having cnt > 1
-- this will work better if you have an index starting with a
```

Same with b :

```
SELECT min(id) id, count(*) cnt from tablename t group by b having cnt > 1
-- this will work better if you have an index starting with b
```

## First solution :

Union gives you ids where there are duplicates for a or b requires 2 indices)

```
SELECT min(id) id, count(*) cnt from tablename t group by a having cnt > 1
UNION
SELECT min(id) id, count(*) cnt from tablename t group by b having cnt > 1
```

Use the ids to filter the table, if you need more data from the table :

```
SELECT tablename.*
FROM (
SELECT min(id) id, count(*) cnt from tablename t group by a having cnt > 1
UNION
SELECT min(id) id, count(*) cnt from tablename t group by b having cnt > 1
) as ids
JOIN tablename on tablename.id = ids.id
```

Now this might not use an index, but you can use a temporary table to have one :

## First solution, using a temporary table (might be faster) :

```
-- using a temporary table to set an index
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ids (
-- adds an index on id, for the JOIN in the result query
`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY 
) as 
SELECT id 
FROM (
-- duplicates on a, requires an index (a) on tablename
SELECT min(id) id, count(*) cnt from tablename t group by a having cnt > 1
-- removes duplicates between both part of the UNION : this might be slow
-- if there cannot be duplicates on a and b at the same time, consider using UNION ALL
UNION 
-- duplicates on b, requires an index (b) on tablename
SELECT min(id) id, count(*) cnt from tablename t group by b having cnt > 1
) tempids;

SELECT tablename.*
FROM ids -- using the temporary table, MUST be in the same database connection, will filter duplicates
JOIN tablename on tablename.id = ids.id;
```

I do not know if setting the index on the temporary table is better then setting one after populating the data :

```
-- you might want to postpone the index after the ids are set
-- using a temporary table to set an index
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ids2 (
`id` INTEGER
) as 
SELECT id 
FROM (
-- duplicates on a, requires an index (a) on tablename
SELECT min(id) id, count(*) cnt from tablename t group by a having cnt > 1
-- removes duplicates between both part of the UNION : this might be slow
-- if there cannot be duplicates on a and b at the same time, consider using UNION ALL
UNION 
-- duplicates on b, requires an index (b) on tablename
SELECT min(id) id, count(*) cnt from tablename t group by b having cnt > 1
) tempids;

ALTER TABLE ids2 ADD INDEX (id);

SELECT tablename.*
FROM ids2 -- using the temporary table, MUST be in the same database connection, will filter duplicates
JOIN tablename on tablename.id = ids2.id;
```

With mariadb 10.2, or mysql 8 you could use window function (I guess).

## Another solution : using vars :

```
SELECT id, name, a, b, rn
FROM   (SELECT *, 
               @rn := IF(a = @a, @rn + 1, 1) rn,
               @a := a
          FROM (select @a := null, @rn := 0) x, 
               tablename
       ORDER BY a
    ) a_duplicates
where rn = 2
UNION 
SELECT id, name, a, b, rn
FROM   (SELECT *, 
               @rn := IF(b = @b, @rn + 1, 1) rn,
               @b := b
          FROM (select @b := null, @rn := 0) x, 
               tablename
       ORDER BY b
    ) b_duplicates
where rn = 2
```

Demo : [with some extra steps to understand](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ccb646b105c90983d226317b0aa645c5)

Edit : this only works if you don t have lines where a and b are duplicates. Which is the case in the example.